# Cloud Function downloading a URL then uploading to a Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

The following code runs fine. I get the "file downloaded" log and then the status 200 code but the file that exists within the bucket afterwards is only 20B in size and is empty.

I have tried to look into the log files, but is filled with lots of parameters such as socketPath and a lot of others.

However, there is 1 potentially relevant log file entry that I believe may be a reason to this outcome (Connection: close) but am unable to figure out how to solve it. Please see attached image[image: cloud function log entry]

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    
exports.writeToBucket = (req, res) => {
    const http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    const file = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/pp-monthly-update.txt");
    const request = http.get("http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-monthly-update.txt", function(response) {
      response.pipe(file);
    });
    
    
    console.log('file downloaded');
    
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    
    // Creates a client
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucketName = 'landregistry_pricepaid_month';
    const filename = '/tmp/pp-monthly-update.txt';
    
    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
    storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
      gzip: true,
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: 'no-cache',
      },
    });
    
    res.status(200).send(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
    
};
```

Comment: What's the original size of the file?

Comment: Hi @Scoop , could you please give it a try checking this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104234/should-i-keep-an-open-connection-to-google-cloud-storage) and check if it helps you? It provides some advice regarding how to upload files to Cloud Storage, including how to deal with closing connections, so you don't face issues with it.

Comment: You're sending a response to the client before all of the async work is complete.  Your call to res.send() should be the very last thin executed, because it will for the function to terminate.

Comment: @Scoop have you solved it yet? if so please correct the code, I'm having the same problem